# Spark: Writing RDD Results to File System is Slow

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, rdd

I'm developing a Spark application with Scala. My application consists of only one operation that requires shuffling (namely `cogroup`). It runs flawlessly and at a reasonable time. The issue I'm facing is when I want to write the results back to the file system; for some reason, it takes longer than running the actual program. At first, I tried writing the results without re-partitioning or coalescing, and I realized that the number of generated files are huge, so I thought that was the issue. I tried re-partitioning (and coalescing) before writing, but the application took a long time performing these tasks. I know that re-partitioning (and coalescing) is costly, but is what I'm doing the right way? If it's not, could you please give me hints on what's the right approach.

**Notes**:

- My file system is Amazon S3.
- My input data size is around 130GB.
- My cluster contains a driver node and five slave nodes each has 16 cores and 64 GB of RAM.
- I'm assigning 15 executors for my job, each has 5 cores and 19GB of RAM.

**P.S.** I tried using Dataframes, same issue.

Here is a sample of my code just in case:

```
val sc = spark.sparkContext

// loading the samples
val samplesRDD = sc
  .textFile(s3InputPath)
  .filter(_.split(",").length > 7)
  .map(parseLine)
  .filter(_._1.nonEmpty) // skips any un-parsable lines


// pick random samples 
val samples1Ids = samplesRDD
  .map(_._2._1) // map to id
  .distinct
  .takeSample(withReplacement = false, 100, 0)

// broadcast it to the cluster's nodes
val samples1IdsBC = sc broadcast samples1Ids

val samples1RDD = samplesRDD
  .filter(samples1IdsBC.value contains _._2._1)

val samples2RDD = samplesRDD
  .filter(sample => !samples1IdsBC.value.contains(sample._2._1))

// compute
samples1RDD
  .cogroup(samples2RDD)
  .flatMapValues { case (left, right) =>
    left.map(sample1 => (sample1._1, right.filter(sample2 => isInRange(sample1._2, sample2._2)).map(_._1)))
  }
  .map {
    case (timestamp, (sample1Id, sample2Ids)) =>
      s"$timestamp,$sample1Id,${sample2Ids.mkString(";")}"
  }

  .repartition(10)
  .saveAsTextFile(s3OutputPath)
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the same code using Dataframes:

```
// loading the samples
val samplesDF = spark
  .read
  .csv(inputPath)
  .drop("_c1", "_c5", "_c6", "_c7", "_c8")
  .toDF("id", "timestamp", "x", "y")
  .withColumn("x", ($"x" / 100.0f).cast(sql.types.FloatType))
  .withColumn("y", ($"y" / 100.0f).cast(sql.types.FloatType))

// pick random ids as samples 1
val samples1Ids = samplesDF
  .select($"id") // map to the id
  .distinct
  .rdd
  .takeSample(withReplacement = false, 1000)
  .map(r => r.getAs[String]("id"))

// broadcast it to the executor
val samples1IdsBC = sc broadcast samples1Ids

// get samples 1 and 2
val samples1DF = samplesDF
  .where($"id" isin (samples1IdsBC.value: _*))

val samples2DF = samplesDF
  .where(!($"id" isin (samples1IdsBC.value: _*)))

samples2DF
  .withColumn("combined", struct("id", "lng", "lat"))
  .groupBy("timestamp")
  .agg(collect_list("combined").as("combined_list"))
  .join(samples1DF, Seq("timestamp"), "rightouter")
  .map {
    case Row(timestamp: String, samples: mutable.WrappedArray[GenericRowWithSchema], sample1Id: String, sample1X: Float, sample1Y: Float) =>
      val sample2Info = samples.filter {
        case Row(_, sample2X: Float, sample2Y: Float) =>
          Misc.isInRange((sample2X, sample2Y), (sample1X, sample1Y), 20)
        case _ => false
      }.map {
        case Row(sample2Id: String, sample2X: Float, sample2Y: Float) =>
          s"$sample2Id:$sample2X:$sample2Y"
        case _ => ""
      }.mkString(";")

      (timestamp, sample1Id, sample1X, sample1Y, sample2Info)
    case Row(timestamp: String, _, sample1Id: String, sample1X: Float, sample1Y: Float) => // no overlapping samples
      (timestamp, sample1Id, sample1X, sample1Y, "")
    case _ =>
      ("error", "", 0.0f, 0.0f, "")
  }
  .where($"_1" notEqual "error")
  //      .show(1000, truncate = false)
  .write
  .csv(outputPath)
```

Comment: Check your executors processing and make sure that all of them receives the same amount of data. And try to change your file system just in case Amazon back-pressurizes your process for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

Issue here is that normally spark commit tasks, jobs by renaming files, and on S3 renames are really, really slow. The more data you write, the longer it takes at the end of the job. That what you are seeing.

Fix: switch to [the S3A committers](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.1/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/committers.html), which don't do any renames.

Some tuning options to massively increase the number of threads in IO, commits and connection pool size

`fs.s3a.threads.max   from 10 to something bigger
fs.s3a.committer.threads   -number files committed by a POST in parallel; default is 8
fs.s3a.connection.maximum  + try (fs.s3a.committer.threads + fs.s3a.threads.max + 10)`

These are all fairly small as many jobs work with multiple buckets and if there were big numbers for each it'd be really expensive to create an s3a client...but if you have many thousands of files, probably worthwhile.

Comment: Ok, I was able to get it to work, I just had to use Dataframes rather than RDDs and to upgrade Hadoop to v3. Though I can see now that no temporary files are being created in S3 (meaning that s3 committer is working the way it should), I still don't see any improvements when writing the results. I'm wondering if there are any other issues.

Comment: you can tell if you've switched to the new committers if the _SUCCESS file is some JSON statistics, not a 0-byte marker. What does it say

Comment: I got a JSON object inside the _SUCCESS file, that's how I figured out that it actually used the s3a committer.

Comment: nice. OK,. at this point you've got the fastest committing of work to S3. One q though: it lists all the files committed. How many files? It may be that some thread pool/connection pool tuning could speed up the final commit

Comment: The files are in the thousands. I tried to repartition (and coalescing), but these operations take a long time.

Comment: I've listed the options to tune. More committer threads == more posts in parallel. bigger connection pool: the http connections used to issue those posts. You need more connections than threads, otherwise the threads will just lock. Try, say, 100 on each. And update us with the results...it'd be great to update the ASF docs with your experience

Comment: I tried doing the fine tuning with no luck. I did a lot of digging and realized that it is a shuffling problem now. I know that because the program sticks at the shuffling stage and takes forever to finish. I didn't face that with RDDs, and I need to use dataframes to avoid the s3 issues since s3a committers only work with dataframes. I looked all over the Internet but couldn't find any clues. Can you have a look at the dataframe version of the code (updated), I don't know what I'm missing!

Comment: no, sorry —I'm not an expert on the performance turning of DFs.

Comment: I have a similar issue (relatively fast computation and very slow write), but I'm using my local file system (and only a dozen or so partitions). Is there an analogous way to turn "committers" on for local files? I've thought about using delta (for other reasons), but I imagine that might avoid file renames that than the default plain parquet format does (but I'm also on linux, where renames shouldn't matter much, right)?

Comment: 1. the local committers are fine; whatever problem you have it's not with rename()